# Random element in STL set/map in log n

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, performance

Since C++ STL set/map are implemented as red-black trees, it should be possible to not only do `insert`, `delete`, and `find` in *O(log n)* time, but also `getMin`, `getMax`, `getRandom`. As I understand the former two have their equivalent in `begin()` and `end()` (is that correct?). How about the last one? How can I do that?

The only idea I had so far was to use `advance` with a random argument, which however takes linear time...

EDIT: 'random' should refer to a uniform distribution

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`begin()` is equivalent to a `getMin` operation, but `end()` returns an iterator one past the maximum, so it'd be `rbegin()`.

As for `getRandom`: assuming you mean getting any item randomly with uniform probability, that might be possible in O(lg *n*) time in an AVL tree, but I don't see how to do it efficiently in a red-black tree. How will you know how many subtrees there are left and right of a given node without counting them in *n*/2 = O(*n*) time? And since `std::set` and `std::map` don't give direct access to their underlying tree, how are you going to traverse it?

I see three possible solutions:

- use an AVL tree instead;
- maintain a `vector` with the elements in the `map` or `set` parallel to it;
- use a [Boost::MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/multi_index/) container with a sorted and a random-access view.

**Edit**: [Boost.Intrusive](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/intrusive.html) might also do the trick.

Comment: You can use `rbegin()` to get the maximum element.

Comment: @larsmans: why can an RB tree not keep track of the number of nodes/leaves in every subtree where each operation updates that count within `log n` time (which is required anyway)?

Comment: @dcn That would "probably" violate C++'s principle of not making you pay for something you don't need.

Comment: 1 and 3 seem like fair alternatives (and I will settle with one of them if indeed no pure STL solution exits), 2 does not work since maintaining the vector costs linear time, right?

Comment: Building the set or map takes O(n lg n) time, so building the vector doesn't add any asymptotic complexity. If you go that road, be sure to store the items in the vector and indices into it in the set/map. The MultiIndex solution would IMHO be the most elegant, would cost the least amount of memory and would preserve locality of reference.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, begin and rbegin (not end!) are the minimum and maximum key value, respectively.

If your key is simple, e.g. an integer, you could just create a random integer in the range [min, max) (using ) and get the map's `lower_bound` for that.

Comment: The `lower_bound` search won't be evenly distributed if the range is not consecutive.

Comment: Nobody mentioned any statistical requirements :-) But good point.

Answer (score 0):

As you suspect `begin()` and either `end() - 1` or `rbegin()` will get you the min and max values. I can't see any way to uniformly get a random element in such a tree though. However you have a couple options:

- You can do it in linear time using advance.
- You can keep a separate vector of map iterators that you keep up to date on all insertions/deletions.
- You could revisit the container choice. For example, would a sorted vector, heap, or some other representation be better?

Comment: Is there a container choice which offers all the above operations in log n?

Comment: @dcn I'm not aware of any such container. That's why it's so important to consider usage when deciding which container to use. You need to decide which operations are most common and which are uncommon to help guide that decision.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an even distribution of values in the set or map, you could choose a random value between the min and max and use `lower_bound` to find the closest value to it.

If insertions and deletions are infrequent, you can use a vector instead and sort it as necessary. Populating a vector and sorting it takes approximately the same amount of time as populating a set or map; it might even be faster, you'd need to test it to be sure. Selecting a random element would be trivial at that point.

Comment: to use `map::lower_bound` you have to already know all the contained items though, I doubt that's really an option.  And `std::lower_bound` will do a silly amount of tree traversal, about O(n) worth.

Comment: @MooingDuck, `lower_bound` doesn't require an exact match so you can pick a random value and find the closest item in the map without knowing exact values. Naturally you'd use the built-in version and not the algorithm - if that wasn't clear perhaps I should have been more explicit?

Comment: True, then you would only need to know the distribution of elements, which is a far safer assumption.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can actually do that with STL, but it's a bit more complicated.

You need to maintain a map. Each with a key from `1..N` (N is the number of elements).

So each time you need to take a random element, generate a random number from `1..N`, then find the element in the map with the chosen key. This is the element that you pick.

Afterwards, you need to maintain the consistency of the map by finding the biggest element, and update its key with the random number that you just picked.

Since each step is a `log(n)` operation, the total time is `log(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

with existing STL, there's probably no way. But There's a way to get random key in O(1) with addition std::map and std::vector structure by using reverse indexing.

1. Maintaining a map m & a vector v.
2. when inserting a new key k, let i = v.length(), then insert  into m, and push k into v so that v[i] = k;
3. when deleting key k, let i = m[k], lookup the last element k2 in v, set m[k2]=i & v[i] = k2, pop_back v, and remove k from m;
4. to get a random key, let r = rand()%v.length(), then random key k = v[r];

so the basic idea is to have a continuous array of all existing keys.